# Apache web server via socket?

Tags: apache

Basically, I want to access the websites hosted in Apache from a socket instead of a port such as 80. So that even if no network is set up in my computer, I would still be able to use the Apache web server.

I remeber MySQL has such a thing that clients can connect to the MySQL server via socket rather than a network connection.

The reason for this is I want to use Apache as a local environment ONLY and prevent it from occupying the 80 port.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are You talking about unix sockets?

Comment: This is a really, REALLY dumb way to solve the problem - Seth's answer is the right solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be able to achieve your goal by binding apache to the local interface.  You can place this in your config file:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8000
```

This will only accept local connections on port 8000.